# Как организовать поиск по csv файлу php?

Tags: php

```
<?php
$input = $_POST['input'];
if (isset($_POST['filter'])) {
    $row = 1;
    if (($handle = fopen("books.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $num = count($data);
            $row++;
            for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
            }
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда двигаться, или что можно почитать по этой теме.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: также нужно сделать фильтр в виде поля для ввода строки и выпадающего списка

Comment: у вас же даже вопрос толком не задан, как можно что-то подсказывать? приведите пример одной строки из csv и пример поиска, что искать (слово, даты, числа).

Comment: забыл скрин приложить